# Add Slide In from Left to Right animation(transition) in addSubView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewanimationtransition

I Try to imitate the `NavigationViewController`, very similar to default `MailApp` in `iPhone`

When clicking on a Mail summary, it should *slide-in* the mail details, and when *BACK* button is clicked, Mail Summary view is to be *slided-in* back again.

This is what I have to animate the transition from Summary To Detail (`removeFromSuperView`)

```
CGRect temp = self.view.frame;
temp.origin.x = 300;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.frame = temp;
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

This is what I have to animate the transition from Detail To Summary (`addSubview`)

```
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFromRight;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFade;
    [parentView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [parentView addSubview:myVC.view];
```

Now, that My First part of code is working well! Where-as the second part, I am just able to achieve the Fade-in animation. How can I bring in the slide transition?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I just need to choose `kCATransitionPush` type for my `CATransition`

```
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [parentView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [parentView addSubview:myVC.view];
```

Update for Swift:

```
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    parentView.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    parentView.addSubview(myVC.view)
```

Comment: And what if I want to remove myVC.view from super view.

Comment: @iBug You can add this line to remove the myVC.view:
        [myVC.view performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)
                           withObject:nil
                           afterDelay:0.5];

Comment: @iBug just change subtype into CATransitionSubtype.fromRight

Answer (score 0):

Or you could check out : HorizontalSlide Segue (just google it I cant get the link, on mobile) its a great sliding transition that is simply a segue that you add from view A to B....

On a side note, if this is in a nav controller, a push or a pop should have a slide animation by default...