# Slide animation for UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I've got this function that cycles through arrays and changes 2 labels. How can I make it so the UILabels come from the right and leave to the left?

```
func updateLabels() {
        self.myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { (t) in
            self.titleLabel.text = self.titleArray[self.counter]
            self.textLabel.text = self.textArray[self.counter]
            self.counter += 1
            if self.counter == self.titleArray.count && self.counter == self.textArray.count {
                self.counter = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22078862/3151675

Comment: I don't think it applies to my case.

Answer (score 0):

Move `UILabel` from Right to left. Add proper `constraints` to your text label and if you want to get animation from right to left set text `Alignment` to right

```
func updateLabels() {

            self.myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { (t) in
                self.titleLabel.text = self.titleArray[self.counter]
                self.textLabel.text = self.textArray[self.counter]
               DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 1, options: ([.curveLinear, .repeat]), animations: {() -> Void in
                    self.textLabel.center = CGPoint(x:0 - self.textLabel.bounds.size.width/2, y:self.textLabel.center.y)
                }, completion:  nil)
            })
                self.counter += 1
                if self.counter == self.titleArray.count && self.counter == 
                 self.textArray.count {
                    self.counter = 0
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. The UILabel does go to the right, but I need that at the same time, comes from the left the next tip. Right now, nothing comes from the left, the UILabel just goes away to the right.

Comment: Also, once the delay ends, it just keeps non-stop repeating the animation.

Comment: you mean UILabel should come from both direction at same time

Comment: Yes, like |<---UILabel<---|<---UILabel2, the | are the edges of the screen, so it would be like this: UILabel shows up, waits x number of seconds, then changes to UILabel 2 with the slide to the left animation. Like if you had all the UILabels on a wheel, and you just rotate the wheel. So when one is going away, the other one is showing up. It's a fairly common used animation, it's just I don't know how to explain it very well, sorry!